# Asigning value to an object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to assign 1 and 0 to a column in a data-frame which is actually a string. In the below dateset 'abc' is to be 1 and rest should be 0

Below is the sample datasest:

```
type={'type':['abc','abc','kk','arr','yg','np']}
df=pd.DataFrame(type,columns=['type'])
```

My code:

```
df['new']=np.where(df['type']=='abd',1,0)
df['new'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
0    6
Name: new, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Why `df['type']=='abd'` ? None of them is that. Seems 0 is the correct answer? Voted to close as typo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this one instead np.where:

```
df['new'] = df['type'] == 'abc'
```

btw:you wrote 'abd' instead 'abc' so you have 6 - 0 :)

Comment: The code is fine and it is working with the sample data i shared. However when i am applying the same logic in a large dateset it is showing just the count of 0 (zero). I don't know why.. what may be the reason.. could not crack the reason